# TextChanged event does not triggered on null when TextBox.Text is absent

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anyone know why when I remove all text from `Textbox1` it doesn't consider it as a null value but rather as an empty string?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == null)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Null";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Input Positive";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By default the value of string before it is initialized is null. But in case of textbox it is initialized(textbox.text). So that only it giving empty string as a value.

Answer (score 1):

null is diffrent then string empty

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.text))
    {
        textBox2.Text = "Null";
    }
    else 
      textBox2.Text = "Input Positive";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `textbox.text` is a string property so obviously it will be compared with a string not with null object! You can try

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.text))
{}
```

You can refer below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox.Text` Don't have any value called `Null` instead try to use `textBox.Text.Length==0` or `textBox.Text==""`

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == "" || textBox1.Text.Length==0)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "Null";
    }
    else textBox2.Text = "Input Positive";
 }
```

Comment: You could do a bit better with `textBox1.Text.Trim() == ""` because if a whitespace gets in there, and it does quite often for users, the confusion will be endless.